# Weblogic threads going into a hang/ locked / stuck state with the following stack trace

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, weblogic12c

When the below error will occur.

<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1415836955862>  <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '81' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "601" seconds working on the request "weblogic.jdbc.rmi.internal.PreparedStatementImpl_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_PreparedStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_T4CPreparedStatement", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds. Stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Unknown Source)
oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(Unknown Source)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(Unknown Source)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1104)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1075)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:480)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:219)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:813)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1049)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:854)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1154)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3370)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3415)
weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:130)
weblogic.jdbc.rmi.internal.PreparedStatementImpl.executeQuery(PreparedStatementImpl.java:372)
weblogic.jdbc.rmi.internal.PreparedStatementImpl_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_PreparedStatement_oracle_jdbc_driver_T4CPreparedStatement_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:695)
weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:520)
weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:516)
weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic monitors its threads and marks them as "stuck" after a certain period of time if they are not returning from a method like in a socket listener loop in thread's run method.
If you want a thread to run till the server or application stops, you have to mark your class with a @LongRunning (weblogic.connector.extensions.LongRunning) annotation. Weblogic will then assign a thread to your class from a different pool and it will let it run forverer.